# Approaching a regression problem with many independent variables and binary response variable with very small success rate

Tags: regression, logistic

One of my friends was asked in the interview following question:

There are 35000 independent variables and 7 million observation over those variables. There is a binary response variable. There is a success rate of 1%.
What will be your approach here?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify: are you asking how to best model the data?

Comment: Yes , plus the reasoning behind it

Comment: Not an expert so I won't attempt a formal answer. Overall idea would be to reduce the number of independent variables, then model with logistic regression.

Comment: The point of the interview question seems to be how to deal with computationally complex models; maybe you could add tags dealing with that?

Comment: That was the only information provided by the interviewer.

Comment: If that was the only information without any scientific context I hope your friend has found a job in a company with a better grasp of statistics.

Comment: Probably the interviewers wany to see how you approach the problem, which questions you ask them, so on ...  very little to say without any context.  A start: 1% event rate means 70000 events, or two events per variable. Usual rules of thumb say 10-20 events per variable is needed (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167551/logistic-regression-10-events-per-predictor-rule/167563#167563 ) so some options:  using principal components as regressors, or the lasso